# How to check size of ::testing::Types template?

Tags: c++, googletest

I'm creating a TYPED_TEST_SUITE and I want to get count of elements in ::testing::Types.
The reason is to perform a static assertion, so I can be sure my tests are up to date with the source code.

With std::tuple following is possible:

```
int count = tuple_size<decltype(mytuple)>::value
```

Is there possibility to do the same with gtests's testing::Types? Or to convert std::tuple into testing::Types in a compile time?

Comment: Read about templates and [partial specializations](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/partial_specialization), preferably in a textbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can do it this way:

```
template<typename...>
struct CountTypes;
template<typename... Args>
struct CountTypes<::testing::Types<Args...>> : std::integral_constant<int, sizeof...(Args)> {};

template<typename...>
struct ConvertTypes;
template<typename... Args>
struct ConvertTypes<::testing::Types<Args...>> { using type = std::tuple<Args...>;};

int main()
{
    using MyTypes = ::testing::Types<char, int>;
    static_assert(CountTypes<MyTypes>::value == 2);
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<ConvertTypes<MyTypes>::type, std::tuple<char, int>>);
    std::cout << CountTypes<MyTypes>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Added conversion to `std::tuple`

Comment: It works and it's simply amazing.
But it turned out that every gtests ::testing::Types has 50 elements, at least my gtests version.

The solution was to create a tuple, and then convert it to ::testing::Types.
Thanks!

Comment: You can convert `tuple` to `Types` same way as I did conversion to tuple, just switch places for `tuple` and `Types`.